# SVN+SSH checkout using tortoise

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I am trying to checkout files from svn+ssh server using Tortoise, but when I enter all details, it gives me an error "Error: Network connection closed unexpectedly".
I have confirmed that my details are correct.

Here are the system details I am using:
-- Windows 7 machine
-- Tortoise SVN client

Steps I followed :

- Url : svn+ssh:///
- Entered username and
- Entered password.

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing at the problem here... but this *might* be your issue.

Some ssh servers will simply fail you if you try too many ssh keys. If you have a lot of ssh keys (even for other domains) this can sometimes be a problem.

Here is an example of this failing when somebody is *not* using tortoise:
https://superuser.com/questions/187779/too-many-authentication-failures-for-username

Can you test accessing the system just using the command-line version of svn just to see?

Even just do an "svn list" on your remote path - and see what errors it gives you.